# timestamp parsing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing, timestamp

I have a huge dataset and I am trying to parse timestamp column to have the following format:
`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:DEC` but the output I have in the dataframe have something like: `210309_131046520_11`.

Hence: I want to split the output column to have the following column:

```
date,  day,  month,  year, dec,  hh,  mm, ss
```

eg: `210309_131046520_11`

`date` 21-03-09
`day` 09
`month` 03
`year` 2021
`dec` 520
`hh` 13
`mm` 10
`ss` 46

I tried to use `datetime` modules but nothing seems to be helpful. Can someone help?

Example of my timestamp column:

```
0      210309_131046520_11.sgy
1      210309_131046520_05.sgy
2      210309_131046528_02.sgy
3      210309_131046528_12.sgy
4      210309_131049712_07.sgy
...
162    210309_132658584_07.sgy
163    210309_132659632_10.sgy
164    210309_132701232_05.sgy
165    210309_132704256_02.sgy
166    210309_132707136_12.sgy
```

Example of my date column:

```
0      131046520
1      131046520
2      131046528
3      131046528
4      131049712
...
162    132658584
163    132659632
164    132701232
165    132704256
166    132707136
```

One thing I attempted:

Using `split`:

```
s_df["date"] = s_df["timestamp"].apply(lambda row: row.split("_")[1])
```

Output:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use datetime's [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to interpret your dates from the standard library:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
dt.strptime('210309_131045620', '%y%m%d_%H%M%S%f')

Out: datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 9, 13, 10, 45, 620000)
```

In a pandas dataframe, this is implemented more efficiently using the built-in, which conforms to the same formatting syntax:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%y%m%d_%H%M%S%f')
```

For details about customizing the format string, see the strftime reference: https://strftime.org

Comment: Thanks a lot!but when using pandas i get the following error: 
TypeError: to_datetime() got an unexpected keyword argument 'datetime_format'

Comment: Thanks @anky :), updated the answer as well

Comment: another question, is there a way to format the data to remove the (_07.sgy) of all the data outputs?

Comment: @Ayy, absolutely! For this I would recommend a regular expression: re.sub(r'_\d{2}.sgy', '', '210309_131046520_11.sgy') -> '210309_131046520'

Comment: wow thanks a lot!!! if i would want to remove that for the whole column, would i replace e.sub(r'_\d{2}.sgy', '', 'df['timestamp')? @rgk

Comment: For a Series I would use .apply() instead: df['timestamp'] = df['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'_\d{2}.sgy', '', x))